# Capturing library f2py call stdout from ipython

Tags: python, fortran, ipython, f2py

I'm using Jupyter notebook with a Python 3 kernel.

If I run:

```
import scipy.optimize
scipy.optimize.minimize(
    lambda _: 1,
    0,
    method='COBYLA',
    options={'iprint': 1, 'disp': True, 'maxiter': 2})
```

I expect to get diagnostic optimization info printed to the ipython notebook. However, this prints to console. I suspect this is the case because the optimization routine is implemented in Fortran, and is interfaced in scipy through f2py. The COBYLA Fortran file does the actual printing.

How can I pipe the Fortran subroutine output to the ipython notebook? As I understand it, it should be the same as calling a compiled C function - so why isn't the stdout shared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. Not easily. That one of the use case that could be covered by the following [enhancement proposal](https://github.com/jupyter/enhancement-proposals/pull/14) to the IPython/Jupyter protocol. Though it's not accepted yet, nor going to happen fast.

The (hand waved) reason is that when using Python you can monkeypatch sys.stdin/sys.stdout/sys.stderr and write to a file-like interface that redirect to do "The Right Thing"™, though when it's a fortran/c/... functions, they often do directly open the filehandles corresponding to the raw streams, and you can't change this after the fact.

The only solution is to control how the process get launched, and change the file descriptor ahead of time, hence the proposal for the "kernel nany".

---

Let's develop (after OP further question).

Python `print` is a function which does not directly print to standard out, it does in fact write to `sys.stdout` unless told otherwise. If you check in a normal python shell:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

You can see that it is a direct wrapper around a filehandle.

If you do the same in a notebook (not in an IPython terminal, that's another story), you will see `<ipykernel.iostream.OutStream at 0x104602be0>` which is a Proxy object around the ZMQ protocol. In an IPython kernel the previous stream is stored in `sys.__stdout__` so you can play around and try a

```
sys.__stdout__.write('Hello StackOverflow\n')
```

Which will print "Hello Stackoverflow" in your notebook server's terminal.
Do not forget the `\n` which trigger the stream to be flushed.

Not that this is not a Jupyter behavior, it is an IPython behavior. The Jupyter side does not care how you do it, as long as you send the stdout over ZMQ. The Haskell kernel likely does the same by providing it's own `io` module.

Capturing the process `stdout` is one solution (that the kernel nanny proposal covers) but it has its own drawbacks. It is simpler to redirect at the Python level, as `sys.stdout` is made for that.

This behavior is neither a bug nor a "Feature", one could argue that subprocess/f2py/pyc, etc... should be able to handle non-standard stdout/stderr, as argument, and the the `nanny` is a workaround to help with these case, which will be

Comment: Darn. But jupyter captures regular stdout (i.e. print()) - I would've thought that's because it just pipes the kernel stdout. Are you saying Jupyter injects some magic into its py kernels which catch stdout at the python level instead? That seems way more complicated, and prevents catching stuff like f2py, pyc, etc. (though I suspect that's a "feature").

Comment: I expanded the answer. Capturing at process level is not easy (https://github.com/jupyterhub/sudospawner/pull/14/files) may have race conditions/threads which is harder. There is also a vague Jupyter/IPython delimitation which is complicated.

Comment: What are the drawbacks of capturing the process level stream? I can ask that in a separate SO question if you prefer.

Comment: There may be contention of streams if parent process wait to read on one while the child wait to write on another, see https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch06s07.html . Add, on top, that a general solution should be cross-os, and you get a small mess in your hand. It's possible. It's not just easy, and take some time to get right. Plus in the IPython case we have network on the other side, so asynchonicity, event loop and backpressure (https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/ is good, but long)