# When python calls fortran, where do format statements in the fortran code print to?

Tags: python, fortran, stdout

Given the following snippet, I expect `captured_string` to contain the `disp` statements from the scipy's fortran L-BFGS-B algorithm.  This is not what happens.  This leads to my question -- what does fortran's `format` statement print to when called by python via a `.pyf` file?

```
from io import StringIO
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

from scipy.optimize import minimize

def foo(x):
    return 1/(x+0.001)**2 + x

string = StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(string):
    result = minimize(foo, [100], method='L-BFGS-B', options={'disp': True})

captured_string = string.getvalue()
string.close()

print('this string appears before L-BFGS-B output')
```

("this string appears before L-BFGS-B output" appears after L-BFGS-B output)

Comment: Format statements do not print anything anywhere. Do you mean `print` or `write` statements?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350116/capturing-library-f2py-call-stdout-from-ipython#41352109 with a reply by one of IPython's developer for the case of IPython. The issue of capturing the stdout of subprocesses is apparently not that easy.

Comment: Is this a duplicate? I don't want to close it single-handedly. At least no yet.

Comment: The other question is about the behaviour within IPython/Jupyter and that is more specific. The current question concerns "plain Python files" but the conclusions of Matt (other Q) apply also here I believe.

Comment: @VladimirF I don't know Fortran77, but the contents of the format statements in L-BFGS-B function like print statements in other languages.  See Scipy's optimizer source: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb/lbfgsb.f#L2715-L2785

Comment: I do know Fortran. Format only sets the format string. It does not print anything anywhere. 'write` does the writing.

Comment: @VladimirF regardless, the contents of those lines does print even if a different line with a different call actually sends it to stdout.

Comment: The content of thoose lines does get printed, but FORMAT is not even an executable statement. It is a declaration. The very same FORMAT statement can be used for both writing and reading in the same subroutine. But lets concentrate on the problem Did you read the link? Do you think it answers your question or not?

Comment: @VladimirF -- it does not answer my question -- it is domain-specific to IPython, and not applicable to e.g. cPython.

A different question I asked which is trying to solve the same problem, does has a solution/answer I figured out that works outside of IPython/jupyter -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381835/scipy-minimize-get-cost-function-vs-iteration/47426734#47426734